# Restricting UFW rule by protocol

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, ufw

I've been trying to create a specific rule to allow ssh and vnc from my local ip 10.1.1.230 but I keep getting errors.

```
    sudo ufw allow ssh from 10.1.1.230 
    sudo ufw allow from 10.1.1.230 to any port 22/tcp 
    sudo ufw allow from 10.1.1.230 to port 5900
```

ERROR: Wrong number of arguements

The only rule I have been able to add is 
sudo ufw allow from 10.1.1.230 to any port 22

Which is great but I would really like to be able to restrict a rule by protocol as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) Man page from Ubuntu, where explain the use of UFW

The error is in the 2nd line, you must specify the port in this way:

```
sudo ufw allow from 10.1.1.230 to any port 22 proto tcp
```